# UITest DateTimePicker

Tags: xcode-ui-testing, eureka-forms

I'm trying to UITest a form Built with Eureka forms on my iOS Swift project.

Here's how the picker wheel looks. Its a TimeRow() on Eureka
[image]

The problem is my UITest is unable to move the DateField. Its only able to move the hours and minutes field. Here's the UITtest code

```
func testSetTime() {
        app.tables.cells.containing(.staticText, identifier: "Departure Time").element.tap()

        // unable to get this to work.
        app.datePickers.pickerWheels.element(boundBy: 0).adjust(toPickerWheelValue: "May 14")

        // these lines work perfectly.
        app.datePickers.pickerWheels.element(boundBy: 1).adjust(toPickerWheelValue: "01")
        app.datePickers.pickerWheels.element(boundBy: 2).adjust(toPickerWheelValue: "00")
        app.buttons["Done"].firstMatch.tap()
}
```

The error after running is as follows.

Unable to find current value 'May 17' in possible values 28 Mar, 29 Mar, 30 Mar, 31 Mar, 1 Apr, 2 Apr, 3 Apr, 4 Apr, 5 Apr, 6 Apr, 7 Apr, 8 Apr, 9 Apr, 10 Apr, 11 Apr, 12 Apr, 13 Apr, 14 Apr, 15 Apr, 16 Apr, 17 Apr, 18 Apr, 19 Apr, 20 Apr, 21 Apr, 22 Apr, 23 Apr, 24 Apr, 25 Apr, 26 Apr, 27 Apr, 28 Apr, 29 Apr, 30 Apr, 1 May, 2 May, 3 May, 4 May, 5 May, 6 May, 7 May, 8 May, 9 May, 10 May, 11 May, 12 May, 13 May, 14 May, 15 May, 16 May, 17 May, 18 May, 19 May, 20 May, 21 May, 22 May, 23 May, 24 May, 25 May, 26 May, 27 May, 28 May, 29 May, 30 May, 31 May, 1 Jun, 2 Jun, 3 Jun, 4 Jun, 5 Jun, 6 Jun, 7 Jun, 8 Jun, 9 Jun, 10 Jun, 11 Jun, 12 Jun, 13 Jun, 14 Jun, 15 Jun, 16 Jun, 17 Jun, 18 Jun, 19 Jun, 20 Jun, 21 Jun, 22 Jun, 23 Jun, 24 Jun, 25 Jun, 26 Jun, 27 Jun, 28 Jun, 29 Jun, 30 Jun, 1 Jul, 2 Jul, 3 Jul, 4 Jul, 5 Jul for the picker wheel "Today" PickerWheel

Answer (score 1):

Well, the framework specifies the problem fully you should use `17 May` instead of `May 17`.

`app.pickerWheels.firstMatch.adjust(toPickerWheelValue: "17 May")`

UPD

I have tried to interact with alike picker in the Calendar app (Xcode 11.4)

Works just fine

```swift
class siguiente: XCTestCase {

    func testExample() {
        // Given 
        let app = XCTApps.calendar.app
        app.launch()
        app.buttons["Add"].tap()
        app.staticTexts["Starts"].tap()

        // When
        let dateWheel = app.pickerWheels.firstMatch
        app.pickerWheels.firstMatch.adjust(toPickerWheelValue: "May 21")

        // Then
        XCTAssertEqual(dateWheel.value as? String, "Thu, May 21")
    }
}
```